# How to sing j2me jar file with full chain of certs? In keystore only one exists

Tags: java-me, openssl, keytool, sign, jar-signing

My company have code singing cert from Thawte to sing Windows applications. I need to sing my j2me jar file with this cert. I've used openssl to convert to pkcs12 format using this guide:
http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/OpenSSL_to_Keytool_Conversion_tips
but I have one problem - I can't add full chain of certs. Just one, no intermediate and crossroot.
So when I signing there's only MIDlet-Certificate-1-1 param. No MIDlet-Certificate-1-2 and MIDlet-Certificate-1-3.
Is it possible to create a chain in keystore somehow?

Comment: For now the only solution I've found is to add MIDlet-Certificate-1-2 and MIDlet-Certificate-1-3 by hands from intermediate.cer and crossroot.cer. At least it works on cellphones.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need another type of certificate - Sun Java certificate.

I don't exactly remember signing process but there are tutorials on this subject. Just try to google "midlet signing tutorial". Or read, for example, this one: http://www.forum.nokia.com/piazza/wiki/images/7/7e/MIDP_2_0_Tutorial_On_Signed_MIDlets_v1_1_en.pdf?20080603115110